# Get PyQt4 to open another Qt window when a button is pressed

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, pyqt4

I'm trying to get one Qt window to display a matplotlib figure in another Qt window when a button is pressed. I have one **.py** file that generates that UI with the button, and another **.py** file that when run, opens a QT window displaying a graph.

If I just run the second **.py** file, the QT window to display the graph opens up, no problem.

However, the problem is that when I run the second **.py** file through the first one, **pythonw.exe** crashes when I click the button to run the second **.py** file.

Here is the code (one **.py** file. It creates the UI for the user to click the button if they want to see a matplotlib graph):

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')
import pylab
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

import matplotlibtest
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(690, 786)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.widget_2 = QtGui.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 20, 471, 51))
        self.widget_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("widget_2"))

        #...some other irrelevant code...
        
        self.plotButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget_2)
        self.plotButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 23))
        self.plotButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("plotButton"))
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.plotButton, 9, 1, 1, 1)
        self.plotButton.clicked.connect(self.showimage)

    def showimage(self):
        matplotlibtest.main()
```

So when the user clicks *plotButton*, the main function of **matplotlibtest.py** is run.

And in **matplotlibtest.py**, I have this code (from http://packtlib.packtpub.com/library/9781847197900/ch06). This code when run opens a QT window which displays a simple matplotlib graph. There is no issue here-- when this code is run, it opens the graph just as I want it to.

```
# for command-line arguments
import sys
# Python Qt4 bindings for GUI objects
from PyQt4 import QtGui
# Numpy functions for image creation
import numpy as np
# Matplotlib Figure object
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')
# import the Qt4Agg FigureCanvas object, that binds Figure to
# Qt4Agg backend. It also inherits from QWidget
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg \
import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
# import the NavigationToolbar Qt4Agg widget
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg \
import NavigationToolbar2QTAgg as NavigationToolbar

class Qt4MplCanvas(FigureCanvas):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        # plot definition
        self.fig = Figure()
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        t = np.arange(0.0, 3.0, 0.01)
        s = np.cos(2*np.pi*t)
        self.axes.plot(t, s)
        # initialization of the canvas
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)
        # set the parent widget
        self.setParent(parent)
        # we define the widget as expandable
        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,
        QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding,
        QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        # notify the system of updated policy
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)

class ApplicationWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # initialization of Qt MainWindow widget
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        # set window title
        self.setWindowTitle("Matplotlib Figure in a Qt4 Window With NavigationToolbar")
        # instantiate a widget, it will be the main one
        self.main_widget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        # create a vertical box layout widget
        vbl = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.main_widget)
        # instantiate our Matplotlib canvas widget
        qmc = Qt4MplCanvas(self.main_widget)
        # instantiate the navigation toolbar
        ntb = NavigationToolbar(qmc, self.main_widget)
        # pack these widget into the vertical box
        vbl.addWidget(qmc)
        vbl.addWidget(ntb)
        # set the focus on the main widget
        self.main_widget.setFocus()
        # set the central widget of MainWindow to main_widget
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)

def main():
    # create the GUI application
    qApp = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    # instantiate the ApplicationWindow widget
    aw = ApplicationWindow()
    # show the widget
    aw.show()
    sys.exit(qApp.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How do I get the matplotlib graph displayed when the button is clicked?

Why does **pythonw.exe** crash?

## EDIT:

If I wanted to pass arguments (x = [1,2,3], y=[1,1,1]) to make the graph, would I put `class Qt4MplCanvas(FigureCanvas): def __init__(self,parent,x,y)`, and when I construct it would I write `qmc = Qt4MplCanvas(self.main_widget, [1,2,3], [1,1,1])`?

In `__init__` for any Qt object, do we run the super's `__init__` to initialize the Qt object's parent?
Why are the arguments to `super(MyMainWindow,self)`?

Why do we use 'object' in
`class Ui_MainWIndow(object):`
but we use 'QtGui.QMainWindow' in
`class MyMainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow)`?

Are 'object' and 'QtGui.QMainWindow' arguments?

When we construct a Ui_MainWindow, why do we write
`self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()`
and not
`self.ui = Ui_MainWindow(object)`?

Comment: are you just trying to open a separate window or display that window inside of your main window?

Comment: I'm trying to open a separate window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you have several problems in your code:

1. You have an `Ui` definition object but you are not using it.
2. You can't user `matplotlib.use` two times in a run (one in your main .py and one in matplotlibtest)
3. If you want a `PyQt` application to run you must create a `QApplication` object
4. Other minor errors involving the layouts

For the solutions check the code, this are some modifications I did to your code for get it to work:

In your **.py main file**:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore,QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(690, 786)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget) #here
        self.centralwidget.setLayout(self.gridLayout_2) #here

        #...some other irrelevant code...

        self.plotButton = QtGui.QPushButton() #here
        self.plotButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 23))
        self.plotButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("plotButton"))
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.plotButton, 9, 1, 1, 1)
        self.plotButton.clicked.connect(self.showimage)

    def showimage(self):
        #changes here
        from matplotlibtest import ApplicationWindow
        self.aw = ApplicationWindow()
        self.aw.show()

#class that actually shows something
class MyMainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(MyMainWindow,self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

#put the main window here
def main():
    import sys
    qApp = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    aw = MyMainWindow()
    aw.show()
    sys.exit(qApp.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And in **matplotlibtest.py**:

```
# Python Qt4 bindings for GUI objects
from PyQt4 import QtGui
# Numpy functions for image creation
import numpy as np
# Matplotlib Figure object
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')
# import the Qt4Agg FigureCanvas object, that binds Figure to
# Qt4Agg backend. It also inherits from QWidget
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg \
import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
# import the NavigationToolbar Qt4Agg widget
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg \
import NavigationToolbar2QTAgg as NavigationToolbar

class Qt4MplCanvas(FigureCanvas):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        # plot definition
        self.fig = Figure()
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        t = np.arange(0.0, 3.0, 0.01)
        s = np.cos(2*np.pi*t)
        self.axes.plot(t, s)
        # initialization of the canvas
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)
        # set the parent widget
        self.setParent(parent)
        # we define the widget as expandable
        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,
        QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding,
        QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        # notify the system of updated policy
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)

class ApplicationWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # initialization of Qt MainWindow widget
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        # set window title
        self.setWindowTitle("Matplotlib Figure in a Qt4 Window With NavigationToolbar")
        # instantiate a widget, it will be the main one
        self.main_widget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        # create a vertical box layout widget
        vbl = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.main_widget)
        # instantiate our Matplotlib canvas widget
        qmc = Qt4MplCanvas(self.main_widget)
        # instantiate the navigation toolbar
        ntb = NavigationToolbar(qmc, self.main_widget)
        # pack these widget into the vertical box
        vbl.addWidget(qmc)
        vbl.addWidget(ntb)
        # set the focus on the main widget
        self.main_widget.setFocus()
        # set the central widget of MainWindow to main_widget
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)

#deleted the main function here
```

Comment: It works. Thank you! I have some minor questions about what you did, which I wrote in an edit to my post. Could you take a look at my questions?